# Why does SIRI automatically stop in the middle of a stream?

Tags: ios, siri-intent

Basically I have tested in two device, it is working on iOS 15.7 and waiting for api response properly but when i am testing in iOS 16.6 Siri haven't wait for response and it was terminated itself and showing message Siri generated i.e. "I tried, but 'intentName' took too long to respond" and Siri stopped there.

Please check the screenshot below:
[image]